# Fastest way to transfer files - faster to download from a local server or via a third party?

Tags: file-transfer, bittorrent

I have an employee in the Philippines that has a very slow internet connection so it takes her a long time to upload her finished work to me via a cloud service like Dropbox, Mega, etc. (Each completed job is about 10GB).

The only way I thought how to technically make this transfer faster would be to skip the upload step so that I only have to download from her. The only two ways I thought of were either her setting up her PC as a server or making a private torrent and I can download from her via bittorent.

I think the server thing is too technical for her so I'm leaning toward the bittorent idea.

I'm not asking HOW to do this (I know) but I'm rather asking if my assumption is correct. Would using a torrent method enable us to skip the upload process, thus making the transfer faster?

Does anyone have even a third alternative?

Comment: You downloading from her machine would be limited by her upload speeds, which is the same problem, when she uploads to Dropbox.  Your thought is not technically sound, her internet speeds, will still be limited factor.  Using a torrent would also present the same problem.  The only way to increase her speeds is through her ISP.

Comment: But, then OP doesn't have to wait for the upload to complete before starting his download.  If it takes 10 hours to upload and one minute to download, it doesn't help him, but if it takes 10 hours to upload and 5 hours to download, that's a gain.

Comment: What?  If he starts to download an incomplete file.  The browser isn't going to continue downloading past the size of the file when he started to download the file.

Comment: I don't think that's correct that my download speed is limited to her upload speed. I once asked about this and though it's technical, when we download at a speed of 8-10MB\sec, it doesn't mean that the server you're downloading from has an upload speed of 8-10MB\sec. ISP's limit upload speeds for technical issues but "technically", the speed CAN be the same both ways but the higher speeds are reserved for a one way benefit of the down-loader\receiver.

Comment: @Ramhound: What dsolimano is trying to say is that if Employee_PC -> Dropbox = 10 hrs. and Dropbox -> OP_PC = 5 hrs., then direct Employee_PC -> OP_PC should be only 10 hrs., so that's 5 hrs. saved right there. There'd be no partial file involved.

Comment: What no one here is considering is latency and Internet path.  It's possible for the connection between point A and point C to be better/worse than the connectin from A to C using B as a midpoint.  It's true however the limiting factor is most likely the upstream bandwidth allocation.  Is it a commercial or home connection?

Comment: The best solution is likely finding commercial cloud or server space with high stable bandwidth that is geographically close to the employee  He/she uploads to that location and then you pull from there.

Comment: Hes anyone heard of or used or can recommend 
BitTorrent Sync https://www.getsync.com/ that seems to solve this very issue?

Answer (score 1):

For a single source to a single destination, torrent would only hurt you. Torrent speeds things up by having one downloader (with a relatively fast downlink) download from multiple uploaders (with relatively slow uplink).

You might set up a server of your own that she can upload to. That puts the technical burden on you rather than her.

If her connection is really slow, shipping data on physical media could be a viable alternative. I've generally seen it done with much larger data sets (>1TB) and usually inside one country where customs won't slow things down.

Comment: If the user's employee has a slow connection to Dropbox they will have even a slower connection to the user.

Comment: Agreed. I have fast Internet so I have no burden. If she's uploading already, I'd rather she uploads to Dropbox. It's the download speed that would benefit me. If I could download from her, and she doesn't have to upload - I think that would be the fastest.

Comment: @ZviTwersky: But for you to download from her, she has to upload to you. The two things aren't independent! The only advantage would be that Dropbox would be cut out of the picture and so you'd save the time it takes you to download from Dropbox as dsolimano said above.

Answer (score 1):

First, consider preparing the job files before transfer.

Using file archive software could greatly reduce transfer time by reducing per-file overhead and by reducing total file size with compression.

Depending on the job files themselves (and business requirements), you may consider other file-type specific methods for reducing file size (alternate video encoding, alternate image file formats, reducing detail, etc).

Second, consider a file transfer protocol which includes resuming in case the connection drops.

Third, I have seen cases where the transfer speed varies between pulling a file (to you, server remote) and pushing a file (to you, server local).  I never investigated the cause.

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I asked about. We already do all the compression and file size reduction necessary. Most FTP transfers can be resumed and torrents as well.